# How I can use another Translation for a template rendering

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, django-templates

How I can say to the render function which language my e-mail should use if I use i18n?

FYI:
It now looks like this

```
{% load i18n %}
{% language language %}
{% trans "Hello" %} {{ name }}
{% endlanguage %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the template in the [`language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std%3atemplatetag-language) tag:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% language email_language %}

...

{% endlanguage %}
```

In your Python code you should pass the value for `email_language` to the template. This is the language in which the e-mail will be rendered as the `language` tag activates that language for that part of the template.